# Выразить побитовое и (a & b) через десятичную арифметку

Tags: математика, логика

Существует ли способ выразить операцию побитовое И через арифметические действия (+,-,*,/,** и проч.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да.

```
a & b = a0*b0 * 2^0 + a1*b1 * 2^1 + ... + aN * bN * 2^N
```

Где ai - i-й бит a, bi - i-й бит b

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ответ, я думаю, это то, что мне нужно, но только я не до конца понимаю, как извлечь i-тый бит числа с помощью арифметических операций

Comment: @McFinley, с помощью деления чисел на основание

Comment: Я понимаю, что это может быть глупый вопрос, но не могли бы Вы привести пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Старший бит `aN = a/2^N`, потом следующий `a[N-1] = (a-aN*2^N)/2^(N-1)` и так далее до `a0 = (a - aN*2^N - ... - a1*2^1)/2^(N-N)`, вроде не ошибся)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Вы, видимо, хороший специалист

Answer (score 2):

Небольшой пример в дополнение к [ответу @mnv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483464/186999)
Суть побитового И - поразрядное умножение двоичных чисел. Но так как обычно используются десятичные числа, то их необходимо перевести в двоичные.
Можно рассмотреть пример перевода числа `6` в двоичную форму

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`6` в двоичной системе представляется как `110`. На рисунке видно, что это соответствует остаткам от деления, причем разряды получаются от младшего к старшим.

Таким образом можно сформулировать следующий алгоритм:

1. разделить каждое из чисел на 2, деление целочисленное, если хотя бы один из результатов 0 - можно не продолжать, так как умножение на 0 равно 0.
2. взять остатки отделения, перемножить между собой - получим конкретное значение бита, умножив это значение на 2<sup>i</sup>, где `i` номер итерации
3. вернуться к первому пункту с результатами деления.

Пример реализации:

```js
function calc(a, b) {
  var res = 0;
  for (var i = 0, c = a, d = b; c / 2 != 0 && d / 2 != 0; i++) {
    res += c % 2 * d % 2 * Math.pow(2, i); // получаем остатки от деления, умножаем на степень двойки
    c = Math.floor(c / 2); // получаем целую часть от деления
    d = Math.floor(d / 2); // получаем целую часть от деления
  }
  
  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = `bitwise &: ${a} & ${b} = ${a&b} <br/> Math: ${a} & ${b} = ${res}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" min="0" max="10" />
<input type="number" id="b" min="0" max="10" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="calc" onclick="calc(a.value,b.value)" />
<div id="r"></div>
```